# Remove Streetview Controls

Tags: javascript, api, google-street-view

I'm working on the front-end of an app I had developed and wanting to remove the controls from the Google StreetView embed shown here:

```
function displayGoogleSV(address_str) {
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var myStreetView = null;

var marker = null;

var address = address_str;
geocoder.geocode({
'address': address
}, function (results, status) {
//alert (results);
if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
//alert(results[0].geometry.location);
myStreetView = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById("streetview"));
myStreetView.setPosition(results[0].geometry.location);
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(myStreetView, 'status_changed', function () {
var heading = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(myStreetView.getLocation().latLng, results[0].geometry.location);
myStreetView.setPov({
heading: heading,
pitch: 0
});
```

Where would I stick in the controls seen here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-controls

Thanks!

Comment: If you take a closer look to the code you linked, you'll see that they set `linksControl: false, panControl: false,`. Have you tried that? **Hint:** `myStreetView.setOptions(...);`

Comment: I see the code I need to implement, I'm just not sure precisely where in my app's javascript I need to paste it.

Answer (score 1):

You should disable them by using the link's options in your Street View's options:

```
/* ... */
myStreetView.setPov({
    heading: heading,
    pitch: 0
});

var panoOptions = {
    addressControlOptions: {
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER
    },
    linksControl: false,
    panControl: false,
    zoomControlOptions: {
      style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
    },
    enableCloseButton: false
};

myStreetView.setOptions( panoOptions );
```